# More concise way to write a series of one-line methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes we end up writing several methods something like:

```
module XyzGateway
  module Defaults
    def pull_sample asynch=true
      'N/A'
    end

    def is_pull_available?
      false
    end

    def is_push_available?
      true
    end

    def connect params
      logger.debug "Invalid gateway(#{self.id}), could not resolve its type. #{ap self}"
    end

    def gateway_init
    end

    def disconnect
    end
  end
end
```

I am simply looking for a way to avoid these `def` and `end` keywords in such cases, is there any way out? In my case above, these are default behaviors and I would love if I could avoid these `def`, `end`.

Edit: yes, actually I do have a module XyzGateway::Defaults for all these.

Comment: aaaah.....just checking which one of the answers below is more eye catching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid them, except by using `define_method`:

```
define_method :is_pull_available? { false }
```

If your goal is just to shorten your code though, you can put the whole method on one line, which isn't so bad for extremely short methods (the fourth method here is probably a bit too long and condensing it like this hurts readability, IMO):

```
def pull_sample(asynch = true); 'N/A'; end
def is_pull_available?; false; end
def is_push_available?; true; end
def connect params; logger.debug "Invalid gateway(#{self.id}), could not resolve its type. #{ap self}"; end
def gateway_init; end
def disconnect; end
```

Comment: When I do this, I usually use `()` instead of `;`, I feel like it reads better. e.g. `def is_pull_available?() false end` (to op, I'd probably omit the leading `is_`)

Comment: `define_method :is_pull_available? { false }` looks good so far

Comment: still I feel the original form as there in my question is more better, for any one it is kinda a quick glance and ok got it, few functions and then their default behavior. On other side say `define_method :is_pull_available? { false } `. one will need to spend a couple of seconds more, ohh...`define_method` has been used, seems some kinda metaprogramming, let me have a quick look, ohh...its simple, few methods with default values, now I got it. no big deal....this is by spending a couple of seconds. Usually one will want to take a closer look when found word like `define_method`

Comment: @JoshuaCheek, all methods in ruby ~= /^is_[a-zA-Z_]\?$/ must return true/false. `is_` ensures that it wont return anything apart from true/false. this is a very good convention

Comment: @AmolPujari There is no such rule in Ruby that dictates that they *must* return `true` or `false`. Your on your own to enforce such a rule on your own, as the language does not do so.

Comment: Not sure where you heard this, but it isn't true. All methods return the result of the last expression (or nil if there are no expressions), except for methods that end in `=`, which return whatever is on the RHS of the method invocation (as this is usually expected in assignments). Generally speaking, if you want the user to consider the result to be boolean, just suffix it with a question mark. No need for `is_` prefix. This doesn't coerce the return value, it's just a way to communicate.

Comment: yes right you both, I was talking about convention, sorry I used "in ruby". It could have been in any language, but as ruby allows us to end function name with '?', we can follow those good conventions

Comment: Tiny point but the convention is to return something that "evaluates" to true or false. So that could be eg the index of an item or nil if is not found.

Answer (score 2):

For static methods you can define hash and use it to define methods:

```
methods_to_define = { 'pull_sample' => 'N/A', 'is_pull_available?' => false,
  'is_push_available?' => true, 'gateway_init' => nil, 'disconnect' => nil }

methods_to_define.each_pair do |key, value|
  define_method(key) { value }
end
```

Comment: Yeah, you _can_ do this, but I strongly prefer the original syntax. If you're going to do this, then it would probably be better to define a method that hides the metaprogramming in a module you extend onto the class (or, if you're not in lib code, and you do this a lot, add it to Module)

Comment: If few classes will use same code, then of course this code must be moved to module. Otherwise it is better to leave it where it is.

Comment: All this define_method's is hard to read, but sometimes you have to do it to keep code more concise.

Comment: Another issue is that every time you invoke the method, you get a reference to the same object. If you were to then do something like `pull_sample << " whatever"` you would mutate the result for future calls. We could `dup` it in the method definition to avoid this, but that won't work since we have some objects which can't be duped.

Comment: Is this issue also applied to static methods, which always return same value?

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too sometimes. It can even make me feel like I'm getting too clever for Ruby. I know that isn't the case. In reality, I think I'm just using the language in a non-ideal way.

When I have a series of one line methods, which I find to be the ultimate conclusion to just about any object oriented refactor, I figure I have also locked in the design. This is probably a fine thing to do if the code has matured around the problem, but probably a bad thing to do prematurely. For that reason, I try to keep the methods a little more willy-nilly and with some meat on the bones.

I also find, that when I have a series of one line methods, I'm probably getting closer to realizing one facet of the beauty of lisp. But Ruby simple doesn't seem like the right place to be doing that, I argue.

So instead, I would prefer to be Ruby like. Well, what does that mean?

I've seen a lot of people do this.

```
def is_pull_available?; false end
```

Knowing to leave off the second `;` is a sign of someone who is at least familiar with that aspect of the Ruby grammar.

This is fast and easy to do, but still kinda yuk.

So what's a Ruby programmar to do? One perhaps with a little extra free time? Well, maybe they can create a DSL. That's all they've really done so far anyway, might as well present it that much more elegantly.

So perhaps we turn

```
def is_pull_available?
  false
end
```

into

```
pull_available false
```

All you really need to do to make this happen is...

```
def self.pull_available(value)
  define_method(:is_pull_available?) { value }
end
```

And either throw that in a base class or mix it in from a module.

I think this is really a step you will want to reserve for when you really want to lock in the  domain logic and accentuate it. The more you polish it up, the more you are going to feel poorly when it changes.

[Metaprogramming in Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) is probably a great book to read if you are interested in this sorta stuff.

Comment: This is an incredibly specific metaprogramming method, the metaprogramming takes up more space than the method it replaces. Maybe if lots of classes have this specific method, but even then, you have an extra translation between looking at the class and knowing what methods to call. I think the original syntax is declarative enough. Maybe it doesn't bother me because the code bases I work on all day are dramatically larger than this, but I'd be perfectly happy with the original code (other than some naming issues)

Comment: Pretty much agree. Which is why I suggest larger, more substantive methods. Methods can be declarative too! I think this is hard to understand in theory, but easier to understand in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in Ruby ~> 3.0

```rb
    def pull_sample(*) = 'N/A'

    def is_pull_available? = false

    def is_push_available? = true

    def connect(*) = logger.debug "Invalid gateway(#{self.id}), could not resolve its type. #{ap self}"

    def gateway_init = nil

    def disconnect = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class Module
  def simple_method meth, value
    define_method(meth){value}
  end
end

class A
  simple_method :is_pull_available?, false
end
```

Or

```
class Module
  def simple_method hash
    hash.each do |key, value|
      define_method(key){value}
    end
  end
end

class A
  # Ruby 1.9 only
  simple_method is_pull_available?: false
end
```

Comment: lets do one thing, grab any ruby guy(or with any language), show him my question code and show him this code above, check out how many seconds he takes to understand on both cases :)

Comment: I thought you want to define methods without using def/end. Mine does what you ask for and is not harder to understand than any approach that uses meta-programming.

Comment: intention was to type less :)